# Prove $ \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\ln(x)=\frac{(n-1)!(-1)^{n-1}}{x^n} $ by induction

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, induction

Prove

$$ \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\ln(x)=\frac{(n-1)!(-1)^{n-1}}{x^n} $$

by induction.

### Attempt to solve

**Base case**

$n=1$

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{(1-1)!(-1)^{1-1}}{x^{1}}=\frac{1}{x} $$

which is true.

**Induction step**

Induction hypothesis: equation is true when $n=k$

$$ \frac{d^k}{dx^k}\ln(x)=\frac{(k-1)!(-1)^{k-1}}{x^k} $$

Induction conjecture: when $n=k+1$

$$ \frac{d^{k+1}}{dx^{k+1}} \ln(x) = \frac{(k+1-1)!(-1)^{k+1-1}}{x^{k+1}} $$

Proof of conjecture:

By utilizing induction hypothesis:

$$ \frac{d^{k+1}}{dx^{k+1}} \ln(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{(k-1)!(-1)^{k-1}}{x^k}$$

$$ =\frac{d}{dx}(k-1)!(-1)^{k-1}x^{-k} $$

$$ = ((k-1)!(-1)^{k-1})(\frac{d}{dx}x^{-k}) $$

$$ =  ((k-1)!(-1)^{k-1})(-kx^{-(k+1)})$$

$$ = \frac{ -k(k-1)!(-1)^{k-1} }{ x^{k+1} } $$

Not quite sure if this is correct since not getting to the desired end result ?
which should be:

$$= \frac{(k+1-1)!(-1)^{k+1-1}}{x^{k+1}}$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof by Induction of $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} (\ln(x))$ = $\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{x^n}$ for $n\geq1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954222/proof-by-induction-of-fracdndxn-lnx-frac-1n-1n-1xn)

Comment: $(1)^{n-1}$ doesn't make sense. You should check the problem to make sure it isn't $(-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @Winther yes there is typo. It should be fixed. It didn't alter the solution i had much (or at all).

Comment: Stick the $-1$ from the front to the $(-1)^{k+1}$ term, and notice that $k(k-1)! = k! = (k+1-1)!$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conjecture for $\ln(x)$ and $\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954161/conjecture-for-lnx-and-fracdnydxn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly arrive at
$$
\frac{ -k(k-1)!\,(-1)^{k-1} }{ x^{k+1} }
$$
If you plug in $k+1$ in the desired formula, you get
$$
\frac{k!\,(-1)^k}{x^{k+1}}
$$
and the two formulas are actually the same: write $-k=(-1)k$, so
$$
-k(k-1)!\,(-1)^{k-1}=k(k-1)!\,(-1)(-1)^{k-1}=k!\,(-1)^k
$$
as you wished.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your statement it's true for $k\geq 1$, then

$$\frac{d^{k+1}}{dx^{k+1}}\ln(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}\ln(x)\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{(k-1)!(-1)^{k-1}}{x^k}\right)=(k-1)!(-1)^{k-1}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{x^k}\right)=(k-1)!(-1)^{k-1}(-k)x^{-k-1}=\frac{(-k)(k-1)!(-1)^{k-1}}{x^{k+1}}=\frac{k(k-1)!\,\,(-1)(-1)^{k-1}}{x^{k+1}}=\frac{k!\,\,(-1)^{k-1+1}}{x^{k+1}}=\frac{(k+1-1)!\,\,(-1)^{k+1-1}}{x^{k+1}}.$$

Comment: This is all in the OP, except your last $=$.